# Iterating a Python List with Non Numerical value as Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the below output of two lists with outputs which will looks like below

```
stats = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '0']]


stats1 = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '1']]



for key in stats:
  if stats[key]['cap'][0] < stats1[key]['cap'][0]:
    print (success)
```

What am I doing wrong ?,
I tried to iterate each keys and compare the values from each list to see if any value happen to be greater than 0

Comment: You may want to look up a `dict` in Python documentation.

Comment: You just can't iterate a Python List with Non Numerical value as Index. Looks like you need to use this instead to get the numerical values: `int(stats[key][1])`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Describe what you want to do, people will suggest better ways for you..

Comment: Do you know that the value of key after each iteration is sublist like `['cap', '0']` which is not an index?

Comment: All - I am getting the list object stats from a function . So I am trying to traverse this list and try to see if any of the value in one list becomes greater than any of the value in the other list  The key is cap in all cases.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri -each sublist is a  index and value like [cap, 0] , where cap is always constant , but the value may or maynot be zero over time

Comment: @Zuckerberg My comment says what you are currently doing with your code and not what you want to do. Best way to know about it is doing is to add  `print(key )` before your `if` condition, and you'll know what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you try to do but if you want to compare values from list stats1 with list stats one way is to make them list of tuples and iterate like this:

```
stats = [('cap', '0'), ('cap', '1')]

stats1 = [('cap', '0'), ('cap', '1')]

for index in range(0,len(stats)):
    if stats[index][1] < stats1[index][1]:
       print('sucess')
```

Comment: Thanks !!  I am not sure if stats comes to me as stats = [('cap', '0'), ('cap', '1')]  like you said or [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '0']]. In the second format , will your solution work ?

Comment: When a value is in brackets [ ] it is an element of list. The thing I wrote in parenthesis () is a tuple which is a different data structure https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm . 
The format you write is a list of lists and I suggested a list of tuples which is more intuitive. It can work as list of lists but it will be more mesy.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach more pythonic is using the zip command:

```
stats = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '0']]
stats1 = [['cap', '0'], ['cap', '1']]
for s1, s2 in zip(stats, stats1):
    if s1[1] < s2[1]:
        print success
```

Comment: This solution gives me a KeyError: 1